# How to compare array keys and overwrite only if doesn't exist?

Tags: php, arrays

I want to merge two arrays where the first is the dominant one and everything that is there will overwrite other with the same keys.

Lets say I have

```
$array1 = [
   'year'  => 1983,
]
```

and

```
$array2 = [
   'color' => red,
   'year'  => 1996,
   'name'  => Jim,
]
```

How to make $array3 to look like:

```
$array3 = [
   'color' => red,
   'year'  => 1983,
   'name'  => Jim,
]
```

So, array1 will always overwrite corresponding $array2 values

But at the same time it should

add this value to $array2 if it is not present e.g. this

```
$array1 = [
   'year'  => 1983,
]
```

and

```
$array2 = [
   'color' => red,
   'name'  => Jim,
]
```

should become:

```
$array3 = [
   'color' => red,
   'year'  => 1983,
   'name'  => Jim,
]
```

How to do this in PHP?

Is there any function where you can set whic array will be the "dominant" one?

Or if not, how to do that via code?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `array_merge` to do that, please try this :

```
<?php
$array1 = array(
   'year'  => 1983
);

$array2 = array(
   'color' => 'red',
   'year'  => 1996,
   'name'  => 'Jim'
);
$result = array_merge($array2, $array1);
print_r($result);
?>
```